# Is there a test case documentation generator for cucumber scenarios / features (test cases?)

Tags: testing, cucumber, documentation-generation

I want to have an nicely formatted HTML page/directory which describes all of our cucumber test cases (scenarios).

I am familiar with the HTML formatter for cucumber.... which is great for showing test *results*,  but I'm looking for something a little different....  I want it to simply show what the test cases are, and be able to see the steps.

Essentially I am looking for something like rdoc, but it should generate test case documentation from .feature files.  Additionally I'd like to have it key off a certain tag format to use that as a test case ID, and use that to link to various artifacts like test case runs/results.

Anyone know of something like this?

Answer (score 3):

[features2html](https://github.com/melke/features2html) does what you want, except for the testid tracking tag.

I wrote it, feel free to use it in whichever way you like. Contributions are also very welcome.

From the description:

> What is features2html?
>
> features2html is a simple script that creates HTML based documentation
>   from Cucumber features. The resulting layout is also suitable for
>   printing as PDF from your favorite web browser.
>
> Note that the documentation is generated from the source Cucumber
>   feature files, and NOT from the test results (there are plenty of
>   other tools that can do that).
>
> Use features2html when you want to create a nice looking requirements
>   specification, that you can email to your customer. You can focus on
>   editing the actual feature files and let features2html make the
>   features presentable to your customers.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't cover everything you ask for, but have a look at Relish: http://relishapp.com/